# BatchNormalization and ELU when only 2 ConvLayer and a small dataset?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

I want to train a CNN with a small dataset, only 500 images. I wonder if BatchNormalization is only recommended when the CNN has much more ConvLayer than only 2?

The goal of BatchNormalization should be to fight against the dying gradient problem. And a dying gradient should only be possible when the CNN has more than 2 ConvLayers, right? And the same reason should be for ELU, when the network is larger, right?

What are your experiences?
I hope for any hints because the case is very important.

Answer (score 0):

Batch normalization has nothing to do with dying gradients -- that's the job for the activation functions. Batch normalization improves the network learning speed and stability.

Generally you want to use both BN and RELU, no matter what is your network size.

Comment: ok, i got it wrong with batch normalization. Batch normalization is more for regulation of the network. And what would be wrong by using ELU in a small network size instead of RELU?

Comment: oh sorry I have contradicted myself with ELU. But it would probably not hurt if you also used ELU for smaller networks? It would probably train longer.

Comment: @CodeNow you should probably explain what you're trying to get of this network, and why did you choose this network size. 2 CNN layers can recognise only small basic patterns.

Comment: Ok, I have 2 CNN architectures, one with 2 ConvLayers and another with 6 ConvLayers. Both architectures are very similar in structure. If I train both with the same data set, I get good results in both cases. However, the goal is to use only a small subset of this data set for training and to find a suitable model. That model should not be too complex, nor should it lead to underfitting. That is why I would like to find good dropout rates, good learning rate and just an optimal Number of ConvLayers.   I don't use Data Augmentation for this case.

Comment: @CodeNow what kind of output do you expect from your network ?

Comment: the accuracy should be as high as possible, but wihout data augmentation. The output should be used for comparison with other machine learning modles that were trained with the same subset.